# CakePHP - Could not find validation handler 1

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

Based on following line from CakePHP:

```
trigger_error(__d('cake_dev', 'Could not find validation handler %s for %s', $this->_rule, $field), E_USER_WARNING);
```

And rules for the field:

```
'number' => array(
            'required' => true,
            'isUnique' => array('rule' => 'isUnique', 'on' => 'create'),
            'notBlank' => array('rule' => 'notBlank'),
            'maxLength' => array('rule' => array('maxLength', 15)))
```

CakePHP detects `required => true` as a rule! When I remove that line, everything works fine!

**Note:** the field already exists into the data:

```
$data = array(
    'name' => 'xxx',
    'fields' => 'xxx',
    'startYear' => '999',
    'biography' => 'xxx',
    'headquarter' => 'xxx',
    'number' => '(999) 9999-9999',
    'tags' => 'xxx',
    'updateTime' => '9999999999'
)
```

How can I fix that problem?

Comment: which validation you want in number field ??

Comment: `And rules for the field:` in future please show the validate property - not an array where readers have to guess/assume where you've put it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jeremyharris on this [discuss](http://discourse.cakephp.org/t/could-not-find-validation-handler-1/258) helped me. On CakePHP 2.x the `required` attribute must be used with a rule; But outside of a rule it will be determined as a separated rule.